# Is TSQL DISABLE TRIGGER scoped to the calling context?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

When issueing a "DISABLE TRIGGER" as part of TSQL batch, is it scoped to the context of the batch or perhaps the trigger is disabled as well for any other concurrent query ?

If the later, what kind of locking is required to make sure the trigger is disabled just for the issuing query ?

Comment: there are times when Google Chrome OS hardware specification of not including the caps lock makes sense :-) http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/12/googles-gorgeous-cr-48-notebook-ditches-caps-lock/

Answer (score 5):

It is disabled globally. It is not possible to disable it just for a single connection.

One technique you might be able to use is to add the following to your trigger

```
if context_info() =  cast('disabled' as varbinary(128))
return
```

Then in the connection you want to "disable" the trigger for use

```
declare @triggerdisabled varbinary(128) = cast('disabled' as varbinary(128))

set context_info @triggerdisabled
```

To "re-enable" it use

```
set context_info 0x
```